# Overload operator to transpose array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm tryining overload operator ~ that transpose a given matrix:

Here's my code:

```
virtual B operator~()const
{
    B a(column,row);
    for (int i = 0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<column; j++)
        {
            a.e[i] = e[j];
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

e is pointer to the memory storing all integer elements of B

```
int *const e;
```

But on the output I've gotten a matrix filled by zeros and with the same size. I mean if I wnat transpose 5x2, I got the same 5x2 filled by zeros.

Edit:
My constuctor:

```
B(int r, int c)
    : row(r), column(c), e(new int[r*c])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r*c; i++)
    {
        e[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure some row column math is required here.

Comment: You need to provide more info about your class `B`: what's it constructor `B(int,int)` does, and how it stores elements of a matrix in a flat 1D array.

Comment: Yes, I wrote also a copy contructor

Comment: As indicated by @WhozCraig, you need something like `a.e[j*row+i] = e[i*column+j]`

Comment: Making that operator virtual is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not filling `a.e` properly: rather than transposing the matrix, it keeps overriding a region that corresponds to the same row with numbers for different columns.

Assuming row-major order, the code should be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<column; j++)
    {
        a.e[j*row+i] = e[i*column+j];
    }
}
```

Since you mention that you've got a result filled with zeros, the logic of your copy constructor and / or the assignment operator may not be coded correctly. Note that since `B::e` is allocated dynamically, [you need a destructor as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: `e[i*row+j]` would potentially index out-of-bound, I assume you meant `e[i*column+j]` (and similarly for `a.e[j*column+i]` which should be `a.e[j*row+i]`)

Comment: @SleuthEye You are right, I mixed up the two indexes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
B a(column,row);
for (int i = 0; i<row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<column; j++)
    {
        a.e[i] = e[j];
    }
}
```

Isn't accessing most of the elements in either *this* or *a*. Only element *0* to *column* and *0* to *row* respectively are accessed.

The zeroing constructor does not reveal how the row/columns are stored, but a guess would be

```
int& B::at(int r, int c){
    return e[r*column + c];
}
```

The alternative is

```
    return e[c*row + r];
```

In this case you can transpose by

```
virtual B operator~()const
{
    B a(column,row);
    for (int i = 0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<column; j++)
        {
            a.at(i, j) = at(j, i); // swap row, column
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you seem to always set the first [0..row] elements in the transpose, with the last elements on every row in the original and stop there.

Second, i don't know how B is internally laid, but because you can specify the size of the matrix, i deduce that the internal array that is used to store the elements is allocated dynamically in a one-dimension buffer. This means that you have a copy constructor to avoid problems with the deletion of **a** at the end of the method. You getting a lot of 0s possibly means (beside the fact that you don't scan the entire matrix), that your copy constructor is not properly implemented.

**EDIT** Seeing your edit of the question, i tend to be sure that the copy constructor is the problem. You don't have a crash because 5x2 = 2x5 elements (so the internal buffer is the same size).